# What should I do to a question that doesn't apply to a game anymore?

Tags: discussion

I once asked [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264269/what-does-clicking-your-mii-in-my-nintendo-do) question about My Nintendo and a specific feature. However with recent updates they removed the feature I'm asking about. What should I do with the question? Should I remove it, or should I flag it to be locked in some way? Or should I leave it as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either delete it, so it will not confuse people who are wondering if the feature is still a thing, or you can leave it as is. I would recommend deletion since My Nintendo is otherwise up and running so our guideline about games that have gone dark entirely doesn't apply.

We do have historical locking, but it's only for questions that historically used to be allowed, attracted some good content we don't want to lose, but would be otherwise closed and deleted. That is not the case here.